# Pandas Fill column values as previous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many columns that must hold their values from the previous row if the condition is met. Y & Z columns decides the values of other columns.

```
Y     Z   A   B    C      D
100   10  20  Nan  22     40
100   11  Nan 15   Nan    41
100   10  23  Nan  24     42
100   11  Nan  16  Nan    42
100   10  25   Nan 26     45
100   11  Nan  17  Nan    45
101   17  Nan  Nan Nan   Nan
```

Expectation

```
Y     Z   A   B    C    D
100   10  20  Nan  22   40
100   11  20  15   22   41
100   10  23  15   24   42
100   11  23  16   24   42
100   10  25  16   26   45 
100   11  25  17   26   45
101   17  Nan  Nan Nan   Nan
```

So basically if the value of Y is 100 and Z is 10 the column values of B should be copied from the previous value of B and if Z is 11 the values of A and C should be copied from the previous values. I have around 20 columns like B and 20 columns like A & C. There are 50-60 columns like D , they should not be effected. And if the value of Y is other than 100 then nothing needs to be done on columns A, B and C

I was thinking of using
df[B] = df[B].shift().fillna(-1)

but I am not sure how to do it based on condition and for many columns in 1 go.

Comment: Use `df = df.ffill()`

Comment: But that will do for all the columns in df. For some columns I don't want to do that.

Comment: I changed the data as well as the question to explain the scenario even better.

Answer (score 1):

Forward filling only rows matching by mask chained by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test membership by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
#if necessary replace strings Nan to missing values NaN
df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)

mask = df.Y.eq(100) & df.Z.isin([10,11])

df[mask] = df[mask].ffill()
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(mask, df.ffill())
print (df)
     Y   Z    A    B    C    D
0  100  10   20  NaN   22   40
1  100  11   20   15   22   41
2  100  10   23   15   24   42
3  100  11   23   16   24   42
4  100  10   25   16   26   45
5  100  11   25   17   26   45
6  101  17  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It will still operate on column D. But how do I say it to operate fill only on columns A, B and C

Comment: @saras - then use `cols = ['A','B','C']` and `df.loc[mask, cols] = df.loc[mask, cols].ffill()`